# Hint button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a hint Button that displays the text when it is clicked. I know how to create using javascript in HTML but I am having difficulty creating it in jquery. Can somebody please give me an idea.
javascript code in HTML:

```html
<button type="button" onClick="myFunction()">Hint!</button>
<p id="hint"></p>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "<em><u>hint here.</u></em>";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have only one button, you can bind the event click and use the selector `#hint`.

The function `$.html` is used to set HTML code to the selected elements.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $("#hint").html("<em><u>hint here.</u></em>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Hint!</button>
<p id="hint"></p>
```